# What is the good number batch size for training a 50 each images for 32 datasets deep learning object Detection?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I have 32 datasets and each datasets have 47 images  a total of 1,5k images

I'm training a custom object Detection in google colab without utilizing free gpu just the normal 12 gb ram from the Google colaboratory (because the gpu have 12 hrs limit)

Is batch size 4 okay or should I make it 8? Thanks

Comment: "The higher the better" is conventional wisdom; if you have enough VRAM for 8 I don't see why not.

Comment: Thank you , I tried 4-16 with different versions